# Failing Oozie Launcher, Cannot Run Program

Tags: hive, oozie, impala, oozie-workflow

I am trying to run an oozie workflow with a very basic script. The script itself is very simple, it takes a csv file and loads it into a table in impala. My workflow looks like this.

```
<workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.5' name='TEST'>

<global>
    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <configuration>
        <property>
            <name>mapreduce.job.queuename</name>
            <value>${queueName}</value>
        </property>
    </configuration>
</global>

<start to='postLoad' />
<action name="postLoad">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.3">
        <exec>${nameNode}/${baseCodePath}/Util/Test.sh</exec>
        <env-var>impalaConn=${impalaConn}</env-var>
        <env-var>xferUser=${xferUser}</env-var>
        <env-var>ingUser=${ingUser}</env-var>
        <env-var>explTableName=${explTableName}</env-var>
        <env-var>stagingPath=${stagingPath}</env-var>
        <file>${nameNode}/${baseCodePath}/Util/Test.sh</file>
        <file>${nameNode}/${commonCodePath}/Util/loadUsrEnv.sh</file>
    </shell>
 ...
```

However when I run it, I always seem to get this error and I'm not sure why it cannot run the program. The directories/files are all pointed to the right places.

`Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], main() threw exception, Cannot run program "Test.sh" (in directory "/data13/yarn/nm/usercache/user/appcache/application"): error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Test.sh" (in directory "/data13/yarn/nm/usercache/user/appcache/application"): error=2, No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<exec>Test.sh</exec>
```

The `<file>` tag tells Oozie to download the file from a HDFS location to the YARN container directory